# Why were Chinese and Soviet five year plans shorter than five years?

Tags: soviet-union, china, communism

In the Chinese and Soviet systems of economic planning, they famously used "five year plans". However, most if not all of these plans apparently lasted shorter than five years. For example, the first Chinese five year plan lasted from 1953 to 1957. Is this simply a quirk of how they accounted things, or is there some other explanation?

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: What is wrong with the answer in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-year_plans_of_the_Soviet_Union), "Several Soviet five-year plans did not take up the full period of time assigned to them: some were pronounced successfully completed earlier than expected, some took much longer than expected, and others failed altogether and had to be abandoned. "  [Chinese Five Year plan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-year_plans_of_China#First_Plan_(1953%E2%80%931957))....

Comment: If the first year is 1953, then the fifth year is 1957.

Comment: Because their massive and demonstrable failures were evident to all and sundry well before the five years was up - they were cancelled to prevent embarrassment to the regime?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Time to edit WP ;) ? ["In terms of economic growth, the First Five-Year Plan was quite successful"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five-year_plans_of_China) (Like certain recent policies informed by tunnel-vision, looking just at some 'well chosen' tonnage parameters, like 'increase in X', or 'result came back positive', things –as tested– _were_ going well…)

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Even the Wikipedia editors don't believe the claims of that post: "*This section relies largely or entirely on a single source. Relevant discussion may be found on the talk page. Please help improve this article by introducing citations to additional sources.*"

Comment: @Lucian Yes, the years are inclusive. The preparation time for a new plan took most of the previous year.